# Cumulative sum array in Javascript, one is working and one is not

Tags: javascript, arrays, cumulative-sum

I'm a beginner and attempting some katas on codewars. I wonder if anyone can help me out and explain what is happening with this code. At this point I'm not looking for a solution for the whole exercise, I'd just like to understand why the const cumulativeSum is working differently for the two different arrays.

I'm creating two cumulative arrays, the code works for the first one (**cumulativeProfit** with the starting array **peopleInLine**) and everything comes out correctly but when I use it for the second one (**cumulativeOutgoings** with the starting array **changeRequired**) the figures are wrong.

My peopleInLine array is: [100, 25, 50, 100, 25, 25, 25, 100, 25, 50, 25, 100, 25, 25, 50, 100, 25, 25, 50, 100]

I have to admit that I don't really understand how **const cumulativeSum = (sum => value => sum += value)(0)** works. I found it after searching on stack overflow!

Very grateful for any assistance.

```js
function tickets(peopleInLine) {
  let changeRequired = [];

  const cumulativeSum = (sum => value => sum += value)(0);

  let cumulativeProfit = peopleInLine.map(cumulativeSum);
  cumulativeProfit.splice(0, 0, 0);
  cumulativeProfit.pop();
  //return cumulativeProfit;
  //logs to console [0, 100, 125, 175, 275, 300, 325, 350, 450, 475, 525, 550, 650, 675, 700, 750, 850, 875, 900, 950]

  for (let i = 0; i < peopleInLine.length; i++) {
      if (peopleInLine[i] === 25) { changeRequired.push(0) }
      else if (peopleInLine[i] === 50) { changeRequired.push(25) }
      else if (peopleInLine[i] === 100) { changeRequired.push(75) }
  };
  //return changeRequired; 
  //correctly logs to console: [75, 0, 25, 75, 0, 0, 0, 75, 0, 25, 0, 75, 0, 0, 25, 75, 0, 0, 25, 75]

  let cumulativeOutgoings = changeRequired.map(cumulativeSum);
  cumulativeOutgoings.splice(0, 0, 0);
  cumulativeOutgoings.pop();
  return cumulativeOutgoings;
  //incorrectly logs to console: [0, 1125, 1125, 1150, 1225, 1225, 1225, 1225, 1300, 1300, 1325, 1325, 1400, 1400, 1400, 1425, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1525] 
  //should be [0, 75, 75, 100, 175,175 etc.]
};
console.log(tickets([100, 25, 50, 100, 25, 25, 25, 100, 25, 50, 25, 100, 25, 25, 50, 100, 25, 25, 50, 100]));
```

Comment: We can see what the wrong output is but what is the *expected* one? Also, what is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Yeah sorry, it is at the end of that line if you scroll across. It should be cumulatively adding the changeRequiredArray starting with an extra 0 at the beginning, so [0, 75, 75, 100, 175, 175, 175, 175, 250, 250, 275, 275, 350, 350, 350, 375, 450, 450, 450, 475]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the way you are using `cumulativeSum` You are trying a function reference and using it between two arrays, because of that when you call the second array the `sum` already has some value in it. The fix will look in the following way

```js
function tickets(peopleInLine) {
  let changeRequired = [];

  const cumulativeSum = (sum => value => sum += value);

  let cumulativeProfit = peopleInLine.map(cumulativeSum(0));
  cumulativeProfit.splice(0, 0, 0);
  cumulativeProfit.pop();


  for (let i = 0; i < peopleInLine.length; i++) {
      if (peopleInLine[i] === 25) { changeRequired.push(0) }
      else if (peopleInLine[i] === 50) { changeRequired.push(25) }
      else if (peopleInLine[i] === 100) { changeRequired.push(75) }
  };


  let cumulativeOutgoings = changeRequired.map(cumulativeSum(0));
  cumulativeOutgoings.splice(0, 0, 0);
  cumulativeOutgoings.pop();
  return cumulativeOutgoings;
};
```